# oracle dataprovider timeout after oracle restart

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have pooling mechanism, which reads data from oracle queue.
All works fine untill I restart oracle db.
Then always I got timeout when calling `this.Connection.Open();`

The problem does not exist when I set pooling=false in connection string but I don't want to do it.

So there must be some problem with oracle pools, so I tried

```
OracleConnection.ClearPool(this.Connection);
this.CloseConnection();
```

But that also does not help, after oracle was restarted, every time my connection is trying to open I got just simple timeout.

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
        this.OpenConnection();
        var oracleQueue = this.GetOracleQueue(queueName);

        return oracleQueue.Listen(null, listenWaitTimeout) != null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {


        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        OracleConnection.ClearPool(this.Connection);
        this.CloseConnection();
    }

    return false;
}

protected void OpenConnection()
{
    if (this.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        this.Connection.Open();
    }
}
```

I use:

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.12.1.022
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.12.1.022
product\12.1.0\client_1\odp.net\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
```

when program is running I stop the OracleServiceORCL service

then with first attemp to openConnection I got:

```
ORA-03113 end of file on communication channel
```

with second attempt I got:

```
ORA-12514 TNS:listenere does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

and with third one and every next one I got `Connection request timned out`

Now when I run the OracleServiceORCL on, my program still is throwing time out exception

when I restart my program, it works.

Additionally recorded logs from performance monitor where I can see something like dead connection entry:

```
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (TraceFileName : C:\Temp\oracle.txt)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (TraceLevel : 127)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (TraceOption : 0)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (CheckConStatus : 1)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (UdtCacheSize : 4096)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (StatementCacheSize : 0)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (DynamicEnlist : 0)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (FetchSize : 131072)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (OCI_EVENTS : 0)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (StatementCacheWithUdts : 1)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (MetadataPooling : 1)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (DBNotificationPort : -1)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (ThreadPoolMaxSize : -1)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (DBNotificationRegInterval : 0)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (DemandOraclePermission : 0)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (SelfTuning : True)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (MaxStatementCacheSize : 100)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (AppEdition : )
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (MetaDataXml : )
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (RevertBatchUpdateErrorHandling : 0)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (FetchArrayPooling : 1)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (PerformanceCounters : HardConnectsPerSecond, HardDisconnectsPerSecond, SoftConnectsPerSecond, SoftDisconnectsPerSecond, NumberOfActiveConnectionPools, NumberOfInactiveConnectionPools, NumberOfActiveConnections, NumberOfFreeConnections, NumberOfPooledConnections, NumberOfNonPooledConnections, NumberOfReclaimedConnections, NumberOfStasisConnections)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (PSPE : 1)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:981 TID:33bc  (REGISTRY) (PSPESupport : False)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:983 TID:33bc  (%s) (ThreadPoolMaxSize : %s [Original: %s; Set: %s; Post-Set: %s])
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:04:992 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleConnection::OracleConnection(2)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:008 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OracleConnection::OracleConnection(2)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:013 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleConnection::Open()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:014 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsConAllocValCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:014 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsConAllocValCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=426
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:034 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsConOpen()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:034 TID:33bc  (HA)    OpsConOpen(): OciEvents=0 Line=1928
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:128 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsConAddRef(): (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:129 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsConAddRef(): RefCount=1 RetCode=0 Line=3688 (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:129 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsErrAllocCtx(): (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:129 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsErrAllocCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=206 (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:129 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsConOpen(): RetCode=0 Line=2561 (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:130 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsConIsOCIAutoTuningEnabled()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:130 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsConIsOCIAutoTuningEnabled()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:130 TID:33bc  (GRID) (NON-RLB) (DISP) (inst=orcl)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:133 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsGetOptimumUsableMemoryInfo()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:133 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsGetOptimumUsableMemoryInfo(): returnValue=0 Line=1033
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:134 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleTuningAgent::Register()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:134 TID:33bc  (TUNING) OracleTuningAgent::Register(): Registered pool "user id=***************************************** with pool Id 710390404
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:134 TID:33bc  (TUNING) OracleTuningAgent::Register(): Tuning thread started.
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:134 TID:33bc  (EXIT) OracleTuningAgent::Register()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:136 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsConAllocValCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:136 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsConAllocValCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=426
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:138 TID:33bc  (POOL)  New connection pool created for: "user id=****************************************" (id: 710390404)
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:138 TID:33bc  (POOL)  Total number of connection pools: 1
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:139 TID:33bc  (POOL)  Total number of connections for pool (id: 710390404) : 1
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:141 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OracleConnection::Open()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:143 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsAQAllocValCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:143 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsAQAllocValCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=2191
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:144 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleAQQueue::Listen()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:145 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsConAddRef(): (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:145 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsConAddRef(): RefCount=2 RetCode=0 Line=3688 (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:145 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsErrAllocCtx(): (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:145 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsErrAllocCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=206 (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:05:145 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsAQListen()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:10:326 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsAQListen(): RetCode=0 Line=2591
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:10:326 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsAQFreeAQAgentCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:10:326 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsAQFreeAQAgentCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=2623
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:12:327 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsAQAllocValCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:12:327 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsAQAllocValCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=2191
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:12:327 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleAQQueue::Listen()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:12:327 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsConAddRef(): (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:12:327 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsConAddRef(): RefCount=3 RetCode=0 Line=3688 (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:12:327 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsErrAllocCtx(): (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:12:327 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsErrAllocCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=206 (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:12:327 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsAQListen()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:15:140 TID:2a84  (ENTRY) OpsGetAvailPhysMemory()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:15:140 TID:2a84  (EXIT)  OpsGetAvailPhysMemory(): returnValue=0 Line=1068
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:17:328 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsAQListen(): RetCode=0 Line=2591
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:17:328 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsAQFreeAQAgentCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:17:328 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsAQFreeAQAgentCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=2623
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:19:328 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsAQAllocValCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:19:328 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsAQAllocValCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=2191
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:19:328 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleAQQueue::Listen()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:19:328 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsConAddRef(): (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:19:328 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsConAddRef(): RefCount=4 RetCode=0 Line=3688 (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:19:328 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsErrAllocCtx(): (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:19:328 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsErrAllocCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=206 (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:19:328 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsAQListen()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:24:329 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsAQListen(): RetCode=0 Line=2591
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:24:329 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsAQFreeAQAgentCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:24:329 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsAQFreeAQAgentCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=2623
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:25:144 TID:2a84  (ENTRY) OpsGetAvailPhysMemory()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:25:144 TID:2a84  (EXIT)  OpsGetAvailPhysMemory(): returnValue=0 Line=1068
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:329 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsAQAllocValCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:329 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsAQAllocValCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=2191
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:329 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleAQQueue::Listen()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:329 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsConAddRef(): (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:329 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsConAddRef(): RefCount=5 RetCode=0 Line=3688 (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:329 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsErrAllocCtx(): (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:329 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsErrAllocCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=206 (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:329 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsAQListen()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:329 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsAQListen(): RetCode=0 Line=2591
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:329 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsAQListen(): RetCode=0 Line=2596
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:329 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsAQFreeAQAgentCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:329 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsAQFreeAQAgentCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=2623
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:333 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsErrGetOpoCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:333 TID:33bc  (ERROR) Oracle error code=3113; Oracle msg=ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 1612
Session ID: 19 Serial number: 21

TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:333 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsErrGetOpoCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=146
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:333 TID:33bc  (ERROR) OpsConCtx=4761632;Message=ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 1612
Session ID: 19 Serial number: 21 
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:348 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleConnection.ClearPool()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:450 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OracleConnection::ClearPool()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:451 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleConnection::Close()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:459 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsConCheckConStatus(): (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:459 TID:33bc  (VALID) Dead connection
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:460 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsConClose(): (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:460 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsConRelRef(): (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:460 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsConRelRef(): RefCount=4 RetCode=0 Line=3864 (0)=0
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:460 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsConClose(): RetCode=0 Line=1429 (48a820)=4761632
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:460 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsConDispose(): (0)=0
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:460 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsConFreeValCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:460 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsConFreeValCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=1454
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:460 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsConDispose(): RetCode=0 Line=1507
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:461 TID:33bc  (POOL)  Total number of connections for pool (id: 710390404) : 0
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:26:461 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OracleConnection::Close()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:461 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleConnection::Open()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:461 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsConAllocValCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:461 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsConAllocValCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=426
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:469 TID:1f40  (POOL) (ENTRY) ConnectionPool::PopulatePool(): Pool (id: 710390404);
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:469 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConAllocValCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:469 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConAllocValCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=426
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:469 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConOpen()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:469 TID:1f40  (HA)    OpsConOpen(): OciEvents=0 Line=1928
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:751 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConAddRef(): (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:751 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConAddRef(): RefCount=1 RetCode=0 Line=3688 (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:751 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConClose(): (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:751 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConRelRef(): (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:751 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConRelRef(): RefCount=0 RetCode=0 Line=3864 (0)=0
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:751 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConClose(): RetCode=0 Line=1429 (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:751 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConDispose(): (0)=0
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:751 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConDispose(): RetCode=0 Line=1507
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:752 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConAllocValCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:752 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConAllocValCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=426
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:752 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConOpen()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:752 TID:1f40  (HA)    OpsConOpen(): OciEvents=0 Line=1928
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:757 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OpsErrGetOraMesg()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:757 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OpsErrGetOraMesg(): RetCode=0 Line=319
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:937 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConAddRef(): (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:937 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConAddRef(): RefCount=1 RetCode=0 Line=3688 (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:937 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConClose(): (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:937 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConRelRef(): (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:937 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConRelRef(): RefCount=0 RetCode=0 Line=3864 (0)=0
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:937 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConClose(): RetCode=0 Line=1429 (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:937 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConDispose(): (0)=0
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:937 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConDispose(): RetCode=0 Line=1507
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:937 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConAllocValCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:937 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConAllocValCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=426
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:937 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConOpen()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:937 TID:1f40  (HA)    OpsConOpen(): OciEvents=0 Line=1928
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:28:958 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleConnection.ClearPool()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:061 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OracleConnection::ClearPool()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:101 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConAddRef(): (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:101 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConAddRef(): RefCount=1 RetCode=0 Line=3688 (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:101 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConClose(): (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:101 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConRelRef(): (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:101 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConRelRef(): RefCount=0 RetCode=0 Line=3864 (0)=0
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:102 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConClose(): RetCode=0 Line=1429 (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:102 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConDispose(): (0)=0
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:102 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConDispose(): RetCode=0 Line=1507
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:102 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConAllocValCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:102 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConAllocValCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=426
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:102 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConOpen()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:102 TID:1f40  (HA)    OpsConOpen(): OciEvents=0 Line=1928
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:281 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConAddRef(): (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:281 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConAddRef(): RefCount=1 RetCode=0 Line=3688 (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:281 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConClose(): (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:281 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConRelRef(): (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:281 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConRelRef(): RefCount=0 RetCode=0 Line=3864 (0)=0
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:281 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConClose(): RetCode=0 Line=1429 (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:281 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConDispose(): (0)=0
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:281 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConDispose(): RetCode=0 Line=1507
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:281 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConAllocValCtx()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:281 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConAllocValCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=426
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:281 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConOpen()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:281 TID:1f40  (HA)    OpsConOpen(): OciEvents=0 Line=1928
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:440 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConAddRef(): (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:440 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConAddRef(): RefCount=1 RetCode=0 Line=3688 (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:440 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConClose(): (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:440 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConRelRef(): (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:440 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConRelRef(): RefCount=0 RetCode=0 Line=3864 (0)=0
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:440 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConClose(): RetCode=0 Line=1429 (48aae0)=4762336
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:440 TID:1f40  (ENTRY) OpsConDispose(): (0)=0
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:440 TID:1f40  (EXIT)  OpsConDispose(): RetCode=0 Line=1507
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:29:440 TID:1f40  (POOL) (EXIT) ConnectionPool::PopulatePool(): Pool (id: 710390404);
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:31:068 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleConnection::Open()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:45:148 TID:2a84  (ENTRY) OpsGetAvailPhysMemory()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:45:148 TID:2a84  (EXIT)  OpsGetAvailPhysMemory(): returnValue=0 Line=1068
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:46:194 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleConnection.ClearPool()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:46:294 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OracleConnection::ClearPool()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:02:48:294 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleConnection::Open()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:03:03:306 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleConnection.ClearPool()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:03:03:406 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OracleConnection::ClearPool()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:03:05:151 TID:2a84  (ENTRY) OpsGetAvailPhysMemory()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:03:05:152 TID:2a84  (EXIT)  OpsGetAvailPhysMemory(): returnValue=0 Line=1068
TIME:2018/03/05-13:03:05:406 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleConnection::Open()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:03:20:416 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleConnection.ClearPool()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:03:20:516 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OracleConnection::ClearPool()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:03:22:516 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleConnection::Open()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:03:25:154 TID:2a84  (ENTRY) OpsGetAvailPhysMemory()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:03:25:154 TID:2a84  (EXIT)  OpsGetAvailPhysMemory(): returnValue=0 Line=1068
TIME:2018/03/05-13:03:37:525 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleConnection.ClearPool()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:03:37:625 TID:33bc  (EXIT)  OracleConnection::ClearPool()
TIME:2018/03/05-13:03:39:625 TID:33bc  (ENTRY) OracleConnection::Open()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the DB restarts, do you remove the invalid connections from the pool using a ClearPool type API or Oracle Fast Connection Failover (FCF)? If the answer is no, that's the likely reason for the timeout or error when pooling is on.

The invalid connections remain in the pool and the app is picking up one of these connections.

The ClearPool APIs and/or FCF are intended to resolve this HA issue. ClearPool is a manual process unfortunately and is not a great solution for this specific HA situation. Most customers prefer to automate connection cleanup with FCF.

To use FCF, your DB needs to enable Fast Application Notification, then turn on FCF on the server side. On the client side, you just turn HA Events=true in the connection string, which should already be turned on by default if you are using ODP.NET 12.2.

From the trace added, it does not appear you have FCF enabled, which is why you are still seeing the problem.

Comment: Updated my question